# MySQL query to return recipients list of a user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am stuck with Mysql query 
here is a table

```
SNDR    |RCVR
--------+-------
admin   |bob
admin   |roy
roy     |admin
alice   |admin
admin   |eve
jesper  |admin
marco   |roy
bob     |eve
```

Now in case of a private msg I want user admin's recipients list 
That is all the sender where rcvr="admin" along with all the rcvr where sndr="admin" but only the unique value
I am expecting result something like this

```
bob
roy
alice
eve
jesper
```

Can anybody help me with the query am going to use it on php , database is mysql 5.5.27

Comment: Have you heard of `distinct` ?

Comment: Why using caps in title? =/

Comment: ya heard of distinct :P i was using two queries
select distinct rcvr from msg where sndr="admin"
select distinct sndr from msg where rcvr="admin" 
what i needed was union . Thank you guys .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a UNION query to get the result:

```
select s.rcvr person
from yt s
where s.sndr = 'admin'
union 
select r.sndr
from yt r
where r.rcvr = 'admin';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7db8/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RCVR FROM TABLE WHERE SNDR='admin'
UNION
SELECT SNDR FROM TABLE WHERE RCVR='admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SNDR
```

from table 
where RCVR = 'admin'
UNION
select RCVR 
from table 
where SNDR = 'admin'